# Uploading an image to S3

Tags: ios, swift, aws-sdk

I didn't touch the AWS library but, I'm getting this error whenever I try to upload an image to S3.

[image: Bug AWS]

I have Xcode 7 and the last version of AWS SDK 2.2.6.

I use this code to upload an image :

```
        // Upload image

        let path: String = NSTemporaryDirectory() 
        let path_url: NSURL = (NSURL(string: path)?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("prof.png"))!
        let imageData: NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)!
        imageData.writeToFile(path_url.URLString, atomically: true)

        let url: NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path as String)

        let upload_request = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()

        upload_request.bucket = s3_bucket_name
        upload_request.ACL = AWSS3ObjectCannedACL.AuthenticatedRead
        upload_request.key = "/prof.png"
        upload_request.body = url;

        upload_request.uploadProgress = { (bytesSent, totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if totalBytesExpectedToSend > 0 {
                    print("\(totalBytesSent)/\(totalBytesExpectedToSend)total  bytes sent")
                }
            })
        }

        //
```

It worked before, but I'm not sure if this happened when I updated the AWS library via cocoapods or xcode 7.

I deleted /Pods, Podfile.lock and DerivedData folder, also I CLEANED the project and reinstalled the AWS 2.2.6 (`pod install`)

Comment: Read the error message. You are trying to create an `NSData` instance with an "absurd length".

Comment: Yeah @rmaddy I think you are right, this worked before. I've just changed the way it saves the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another way to save the temporary file.

```
    // temporary

    let fileName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString.stringByAppendingString(".png")
    let fileURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)!

    do {
        try imageData.writeToURL(fileURL, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
    } catch _ {
        print("didn't write into it.")
    }

    // ...
```

And update the body url.

```
    upload_request.body = fileURL;
```